# How to assign material only to some faces?

Tags: materials

[image]

Last two days, I have been facing a setting issue in my Blender 3.0. I want to fill only one side of the cube face with material, but it fills the whole cube object.
Does anyone know how to correct my settings or something? I tried many ways but couldn't get success.

Answer (score 3):

All faces are assigned the first material by default. It will work if you have more than one material added to the object. First will be assigned to all faces, then you select some faces that you want to have different material and assign the second material to them.